# Avoid view repetition by reusing title and other key tidbits in a global variable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, global-variables, title, interpolation

Highly related questions to help me refactor and streamline my code.

**First**

My view starts with `<% provide(:title, 'My Title') %>`

But then in the rest of the view, in headers or in paragraphs or what not, 'My Title' repeats itself a LOT... is there a way that I can just call it again? I tried, for example: `<h4>:title</h4>` which did not work.

**Second**

Also in the same view, I repeat, if you're interested, please contact me (with a link) a lot. I'd like to also replace this sentence with a symbol of some kind.

Now initially, I had thought about using a global variable like so

```
<p>Yada dada beginning text. <%= @@contactme %> </p>
```

And then delcaring it in the controller (btw, reason it's global is because multiple methods refer to the same view, it's actually a partial), but the problem is that I'm not even sure it's possible to declare a global variable with HTML and routes in it like so.

```
class Controller do
    @@contactme = "If you're interested, please <a href='<%= new_contact_path %>'>please contact me</a>".html_safe
end
```

And even if it were possible, it's not exactly working for me. Before the variable even has a chance to render I get: `uninitialized class variable @@contactme in ActionView::CompiledTemplates`

Thanks!

Comment: u should write <%= yield(:title) %>, instead of <h4>:title</h4>

Comment: "@@contactme" is a class variable, to use it u have to do Controller.contactme to get its value, but don't know whether it will give output in the view or not, but m sure if u use "@contactme" it is accessible in view also. @contactme is instance vaiable.

Comment: Thanks Rahul! So I changed @@ to @, and now it's not throwing the error, but nor is it loading the content. Any idea on what I might have written wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

application.html.erb

```
<%= content_for :title %>
```

posts/index.html.erb # for example

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  Awesome title
<% end %>
```

More information here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

**Second:**

```
class Post
  CONTACTME = "If you're interested, please <a href='/contacts/new'>please contact me</a>".html_safe
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= Post::CONTACTME %>
```

Comment: Just tried this, got the error: `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Controller`

Comment: Put `CONTACTME` in any of your model class (for example `Post`) and change from `Controller::CONTACTME` to `Post::CONTACTME`

Comment: Ok if it's in the model class, will it be accessible from any method in the controller? Trying this now

Comment: It should be, like a global variable.

Comment: Ok getting SO close! So when I put in that path exactly it tries to take me to a path `calhost:3000/photographer/<%= new_contact_path %>`, so of course I removed the interpolation signs, and now it's taking me to `localhost:3000/photographer/new_contact_path`. Yet this is still not right, the path is supposed to be `localhost:3000/contacts/new`, and when I use `new_contact_path` elsewhere it works, so not sure why it's leading elsewhere here. Thoughts?

Comment: `CONTACTME = "If you're interested, please <a href='/contacts/new'>please contact me</a>".html_safe` Because model do not have acsess to controller helpers. Other solution put `CONTACTME` to your `ApplicationController` like so: `@contactme = "<%= new_contact_path %> and text . . ."`

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks! So actually I tried to put it into my ApplicationController, but I couldn't figure out the right syntax to get it to work and unfortunately the answer from Gordon Gao wasn't quite right either. Do you know what that syntax might be? Obviously no need to respond since problem is already solved, but if you feel like scratching my itch, please do comment on Gordon's earlier answer above

Comment: I think the best solution for "contact link" is to create a separate partial "views/shared/_contacts.html.erb" and paste `= render 'shared/contacts'` in anywhere you want.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but I'm already in a partial and didn't want to render a partial in a partial, it would start building and taking too long in the future

Comment: There's no any elegant solution for the goal. Just partials or wierd way with constants :) But you should take any solution you want.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, like Rahul said, use yeild.

For the second, I am not sure generating views within controller is a good behaviour, and you will also face multiple layer erb rendering (<% tag with another <% tag) in this case, (which I am not sure if it will work)

try this:

```
class Controller do
  @contactme = "If you're interested, #{link_to 'please contact me', new_contact_path}"
end
```

Edit:

`new_contact_path` may only be used in views, not controllers. Please try to use partials for your case.

create app/views/shared/_contactme.html.erb with following content:

```
If you're interested, <%= link_to 'please contact me', new_contact_path %>
```

Then in your original views

```
<p>Yada dada beginning text. <%= render 'shared/contactme' %></p>
```

Comment: Just tried this, looks like it thinks the route is a method. Got the error `undefined local variable or method `new_contact_path' for StaticPagesController:Class`

Comment: I guess the routes shortcut can only be used in views and not in controller. Again, I do not think creating html content within controller is a good one. If you need to use this "Please Contact Me" snippets quite often in your views, I think you should put it into a view partial, which is more suitable for your case.